# Problem when importing sqlalchemy modules

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am following the FastAPI tutorial and I am still figuring out why the following code does not run successfully.

```
import sqlalchemy


SQLACHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "sqlite:///./sql_app.db"
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    SQLACHEMY_DATABASE_URL, connect_args={"check_same_thread": False}
)

SessionLocal = sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
```

But if I change the import from`import sqlalchemy` to `import sqlalchemy.orm`, the code works. Additionally, my vscode does not recognize the submodules of sqlalchemy in this line: `SessionLocal = sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)`

Am I missing something?

Comment: What version of python do you have installed?

Comment: I am using python 3.8.10 on ubuntu 20.04.